# What exactly ARE $\pi$ and $e$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, number-theory

First of all, apologies if this is a bad question. I don't really know how to phrase it.

I first got introduced to  $\pi$ in elementary school, where it was presented as a ratio for a circle's area. I thought it was some special number that had to do with circles. You can imagine my confusion when I found it popping up in stuff that seemingly had nothing to do with circles, like in the Wallis formula or the Basel Problem. Same with $e$. I thought it was this financial growth thing, so I got pretty confused when it showed up in stuff like the Probability Distribution, and Euler's identity. Right now, they seem like two magic numbers with magical properties - same thing with $\cos$ and $\sin$ - magical equations that give you ratios of lengths.

Could someone explain what the heck exactly is the significance of $e$ and  $\pi$? Beyond circles, beyond geometry. Because they certainly seem to be more than just that.

Comment: what exactly is $2$? Is it the smallest prime number or is it defined by $\ln(e^2)$

Comment: If you google search “3b1b Wallis pi” or “3b1b Basel pi”, you’ll see that 3 blue 1 brown has created videos for pi’s connections to the Wallis product and the Basel problem. Honestly 2 of the most awesome videos ever.

Comment: $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$.

Comment: That a number pops up in two seemingly disconnected contexts is a great motivation/opportunity for mathematicians to find a link between those seemingly disconnected contexts.

Comment: The numbers $e, \pi$ occur in so many different contexts and that makes them so interesting and worthwhile to study.

Comment: @Michael Better phrased as $e^{i \pi}$ = -1, because 1 and 0 are irrelevant here - the equation is telling you that taking e to that i'th multiple of pi takes you pi radians around the unit circle.

Comment: @AaronCruz : The phrasing I gave is generally viewed as being the "most beautiful."  The equation $e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0$ contains the main fundamental constants of math ($0,1,i,e,\pi$), they all occur once and only once, and the main operations of arithmetic (addition, multiplication, exponentiation), all once and only once.  And there is nothing else cluttering the equation. You cannot beat that aesthetic! (See also _The Art of Mathematics_ by Jerry King).

Comment: I concur with Michael. $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ holds more wonder in its presentation for me.

Comment: @Michael, sure, if you believe cramming as many operations and numbers into as small a space as possible is 'wonderful' or 'beautiful'. When will you ever write 0 in that form? Never, although if you wanted to find a principal root of -1, you might write it as $e^{i\pi}$. Your form has stripped the equation of all its meaning - and meaning is what makes math beautiful. But if you can find wonder in clutter and unnecessary operations, you do you.

Comment: You may probably want to take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-o3eB9sfls) by 3blue1brown. It explains where $\pi$ comes from in the Besel problem

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this video](https://youtu.be/seUU2bZtfgM) explaining about transcendental numbers

Comment: I was referred to the introduction of Rudin's Real and Complex analysis, where he describes pi as a period (or more specifically, 2 pi i)

Answer (score 10):

This may surprise you, but every appearance of $\pi$, no matter how crazy-looking it is, traces to the involvement of a circle somewhere.

For example, where does the Wallis product come from? From evaluating $\frac{\sin x}{x}=\prod_{k\ge 1}(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2})$ at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ (i.e. a quarter-turn from $x=0$). And though we teach trigonometry to students with right-angled triangles, you can embed those triangles in a circle of which the hypotenuse is a radius, and generalise the cosine and sine beyond acute angles so that, if in the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ we consider a radius $(1,\,0)$ and another forming an anticlockwise angle $\theta$ with it, the latter meets the circle at $(\cos\theta,\,\sin\theta)$. So ultimately, these functions are defined with circles.

What about the Basel problem? We can prove $\sum_{k\ge 1}k^{-2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ by using the fact that acute $x$ satisfy $\cot^2x\le x^{-2}\le\csc^2 x=1+\cot^2 x$, which we sum over $x\in\{\frac{k\pi}{2m+1}|1\le k\le m\}$. (The sum of the squared cotangents can be obtained [from a polynomial's coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#The_proof).) So once again, it leads back to trigonometry, hence circles.

Similarly, every appearance of $e$, no matter how crazy-looking it is, traces to either of its equivalent definitions (1) $e:=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ or (2) $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x,\,e>0$. (1) implies $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n\approx e^x$ for $x\ll n$, from which we can deduce the central limit theorem using characteristic functions. But this proof also uses $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$, which can be proven by combining (2) with a proof that $\cos x,\,\sin x$ satisfy $y''=-y$.

Why does $\pi$ keep coming up? Because multivariable symmetries frequently concern tracing over the surface of a circle, sphere or hypersphere, which traces back to circles. Why does $e$ keep coming up? Because so many problems hinge on rates of change, which automatically include exponential functions if the differential equations involved take a certain form.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you read the article on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Definition) about the definition of $\pi$. It is suggested to start from the cosine function, which can be defined as a series or a differential equation. The reason is that usually in calculus you learn series and derivatives before integral. If you have this notions, then one can derive the circumference of the circle by integration, so $\pi$ as defined in antiquity is a consequence of a calculation performed 3000 years later. Similar with $e$, if you start with either the Taylor series representation or the basic definition that $\frac{de^x}{dx}=e^x$, you can then derive all properties you described in your question.